# Nested JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to have the following structure for JSON.

Expected JSON:

```
[
[count:5,applied:{key:value},{key:value},{key:value},{key:value},{key:value}],
[count:2,notapplied:{key:value},{key:value}]
]
```

Below is my code:

```
$json = array(); 
$json[]=array("Count"=>5);
while($mydata=mysql_fetch_array($myquery))
{
   $json[]=array("key" => $mydata[0]);
}
json_encode($json);
```

The above code is just creating the following JSON structure,
I need to have the following structure for JSON.

```
[{count:5},{key:value},{key:value},{key:value},{key:value},{key:value}]
```

Any pointers as of how to achieve the expected JSON?Thanks for your help.

EDITED:
I have written following code:

```
$json = array(); 
  $json[]=array("Count"=>5);
while($mydata=mysql_fetch_array($myquery))
    {
     $json['applied'][]=array("key" => $mydata[0]);   
    }
  $json[]=array("Count"=>2);
while($mydata1=mysql_fetch_array($myquery1))
    {
     $json['not applied'][]=array("key" => $mydata[0]);   
    }
```

But above code does not create the notapplied part :( Any help on where I am going wrong.

Comment: Are we supposed to magically guess what `applied` and `notapplied` is?

Comment: Your expected JSON is not valid JSON. Everything inside `{...}` must be `key:value`. Did you mean `applied: [ {key:value}, {key:value} ]`?

Comment: Apologies.'Applied' indicates "Jobs applied by the user" and 'not applied' indicates 'Jobs not applied by the user'.

Comment: Where are the applied and non-applied jobs in the query results?

Comment: My suggestion is simply to get the data structure the way you want it in PHP, then JSON encode it.  You don't yet have the data structure right.  Make sure you understand how objects, associative arrays, and numerically-indexed arrays are serialized into JSON.  JSON is just a serialization method, not some magic format that you need to figure out how to represent data in.

Comment: @barmar,I am expecting an array and not an object.Hence I have enclosed in a [..]

Comment: You enclosed the outer thing in an array, but not the value of `applied:`.

Comment: I am new to JSON.Could you please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: array elements should be enclosed in square braces[] and object properties should be enclosed in curly braces{} use them apropriately
an remember to encode/strengify before sending and decode upon receival and you should be fine

Comment: I have edited.Is the edited version correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your key:value pairs in another array.

Change it to this:

```
$json = array(); 
$json[]=array("Count"=>5);
$applied = true;
while($mydata=mysql_fetch_array($myquery))
{
   $json[($applied ? 'applied' : 'notapplied')][]=array("key" => $mydata[0]);
}
json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Thanks dickw.I have two separate sql queries to fill up the data for  applied and not applied :(

Comment: In your editted code, change $json['not applied'][]=array("key" => $mydata[0]); to $json['not applied'][]=array("key" => $mydata1[0]);